# Setting multiple macro parameters in one lua block

Tags: macros, luatex

I have a Latex macro with multiple parameters, most of which I want to set in a `\directlua` command. However, this works only if I also print the macro itself in the `\directlua` command:

Works:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\withmanyparameters[8]{%
  #1 -- #2 -- #3 -- #4 -- #5 -- #6 -- #7 -- #8
} 

\begin{document}
% all in lua
\directlua{%
   tex.sprint("\string\\withmanyparameters")
   for i = 1,8 do
     tex.sprint("{l" .. tex.round(i) .. "}")
   end
}  

% individual params in lua:
\withmanyparameters{1}{2}{3}{\directlua{tex.sprint("l4")}}{\directlua{tex.sprint("l5")}}{6}{7}{8}
\end{document}
```

However, setting a subset of the parameters in one `\directlua` block doesn't work:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\withmanyparameters[8]{%
  #1 -- #2 -- #3 -- #4 -- #5 -- #6 -- #7 -- #8
} 

\begin{document}
\withmanyparameters{1}{2}{3}\directlua{%
   for i = 3,8 do
     tex.sprint("{l" .. i .. "}")
   end
}

\end{document}
```

This code fails with

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
```

Is there a way to make this work? Of course I could always print the full marco from luatex by handing the macro name and the other parameters also to lua. However, in my case, there are multiple versions of `\withmanyparameters`, which have different numbers of parameters. Mapping all of this into a lua function would be quite complex, therefore I only want to set the final four parameters from a lua function.

Comment: the first 4 parameters that you pass to your macro are `{1}{2}{3}\directlua` so it all goes wrong from there, you would need to use an `\expandafter` chain, or `\expanded` to expand `\directlua` before calling `\withmanyparameters` or change the call order so you call `\directlua` first

Answer (score 1):

The first 4 parameters that you pass to your macro are `{1}{2}{3}\directlua` so it all goes wrong from there, you would need to use an `\expandafter` chain, or as below `\expanded` to expand \directlua before calling `\withmanyparameters` or change the call order so you call `\directlua` first

For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\withmanyparameters[8]{%
  #1 -- #2 -- #3 -- #4 -- #5 -- #6 -- #7 -- #8
} 

\begin{document}
\expanded{\noexpand\withmanyparameters{1}{2}{3}\directlua{%
   for i = 3,8 do
     tex.sprint("{l" .. i .. "}")
   end
}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\withmanyparameters[8]{%
  #1 -- #2 -- #3 -- #4 -- #5 -- #6 -- #7 -- #8
} 
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}

\begin{document}
\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{%
  \directlua{%
     for i = 4,8 do
       tex.sprint("{l" .. i .. "}")
     end
  }%
}{\withmanyparameters{1}{2}{3}}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\withmanyparameters[8]{%
  #1 -- #2 -- #3 -- #4 -- #5 -- #6 -- #7 -- #8
} 

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\exp_args:Nno\use:nn{\withmanyparameters{1}{2}{3}}{\directlua{
   for~i~=~4,8~do~
     tex.sprint("{l"~..~i~..~"}")~
   end
}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]